# How to show ONLY the Preview Mode in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it not possible to have ONLY the Assistant Editor Preview Mode visible in Xcode? The main story board gets in the way. There's no way to remove that part or "un-dock" the preview part?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag it to the left but it doesn't let you drag it all the way. You can also double-click the white area and it will zoom out so you can see all previews at once but the other panes still stay open and the zoom is much too small. Preview mode window in full-screen and scaling is definitely needed in Xcode.